# /dev/video0 not found

Tags: video, camera, lsusb

I am using an fx2lp camera in Ubuntu 18.04 (kernel version 4.15.0-76-generic) to capture the image but I’m getting the error:

> /dev/video0 not found

When I am trying the `lsusb` command, the device is detected.

```
mangoh@mangoh-vm:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04b4:00f1 Cypress Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021 VirtualBox USB Tablet
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```